dynamic insertion of missing using tidyverse
I am working a couple of functions that will save me a lot of time in my data wrangling workflow.  I am trying to provide R with a list of columns.  I want to loop over those columns looking for specific values.  When coming across those values, I want to replace them with NA rather than leave those values.  My issue is sometimes I will have factors in my data.  When I coerce them back to numeric form, the functions are not picking up on the values of interest.  Is there some way to fix this?  Here is my code and the output I get from this code:
convert_factors_to_numeric <- function(df, columns) {
  df %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(columns), ~ if (is.factor(.x)) as.numeric(as.character(.x)) else .x))
}

handle_missing_values <- function(df, columns, missing_codes = c(-7, -5, -8, -9, 99)) {
  df %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(columns), ~ {
      # Loop through each missing code and apply na_if
      temp <- .x
      for (code in missing_codes) {
        temp <- na_if(temp, code)
      }
      temp
    }))
}

library(dplyr)

# Sample reproducible data
set.seed(123)
df <- tibble(
  age = c(15, 16, 17, 15, -9),  # Added missing code (-9) to age
  qn = factor(sample(c(1, 2, 3, -7, -9), 5, replace = TRUE)),  # qntransgender as factor
  q1 = factor(sample(1:2, 5, replace = TRUE)),  # q1 as a factor
  q2 = sample(1:5, 5, replace = TRUE),
  q3 = sample(1:4, 5, replace = TRUE)
)

# Step 1: Convert factors to numeric
df_converted <- convert_factors_to_numeric(df, c("qn", "q1", "age"))
is.numeric(df_converted$q1)

# Step 2: Handle custom missing values (-7, -9, etc.)
df_final <- handle_missing_values(df_converted, c("qn", "q1", "age"))

print(df_final)


A tibble: 5 × 5
    age    qn    q1    q2    q3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1    15     3     1     2     1
2    16     3     2     3     4
3    17     2     2     5     1
4    15     2     2     3     1
5    NA     3     1     3     1

As you can see qn should have two NAs in rows 4 and 5 as follows:
A tibble: 5 × 5
    age    qn    q1    q2    q3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1    15     3     1     2     1
2    16     3     2     3     4
3    17     2     2     5     1
4    15     NA     2     3     1
5    NA     NA    1     3     1

What am I missing? How can I fix my code to get this output?

Your function looks fine. The issue is  that qn in your data frame doesn't contain any of the missing codes. With set.seed(123), sample() is always picking 2s and 3s, never -7 or -9. Try different seed values until your test df contains one of these values.

set.seed(42) ftw

"As you can see qn should have two NAs in rows 4 and 5 as follows" I don't see that.. none of those are missing_codes.

Simpler:
handle_missing_values <- function(df, columns, missing_codes = c(-7, -5, -8, -9, 99)) {
  df |> mutate(across(all_of(columns), ~if_else(.x %in% missing_codes, NA, .x)))
}


Using a for loop might be easier to read, and faster.
> df_converted
  age qn q1 q2 q3
1  15  3  2  1  3
2  16  2  1  2  1
3  17 -9  1  3  4
4  15 -7  2  5  1
5  -9  1  2  3  1
> 
> mis <- c(-7, -5, -8, -9, 99)
> cols <- c("qn", "q1", "age")
> 
> for (m in mis) {
+   tmp <- df_converted[cols]
+   tmp[tmp == m] <- NA
+   df_converted[cols] <- tmp
+ }
> 
> df_converted
  age qn q1 q2 q3
1  15  3  2  1  3
2  16  2  1  2  1
3  17 NA  1  3  4
4  15 NA  2  5  1
5  NA  1  2  3  1

